# calcular diferencia en dias de dos fechas al importar fichero a base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una duda en la que espero podáis ayudarme. Al importar un fichero de excel a la base de datos con php, me gustaría calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas en días para que al importar el dato esté el cálculo hecho. Las fechas son fechaEnvio y la fechaActual. El calculo sería en el campo "contador"
El archivo php sería el siguiente:

```
<?php
require 'funcs/conexion.php';
include "class.upload.php";

if(isset($_FILES["name"])){
    $up = new Upload($_FILES["name"]);
    if($up->uploaded){
        $up->Process("uploads/");
        if($up->processed){
            /// leer el archivo excel
            require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
            $archivo = "uploads/".$up->file_dst_name;
            $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($archivo);
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo);
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
            $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
           for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
                $x_noCliente = $sheet->getCell("A".$row)->getValue();
                $x_nombreCliente = $sheet->getCell("B".$row)->getValue();
                $x_fechaEnvio  = $sheet->getCell("F".$row)->getValue();
                $x_fechaEnvio =  !empty($x_fechaEnvio) ? date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($x_fechaEnvio)) : null;
                $x_fechaActual = $sheet->getCell("H".$row)->getValue();
                $x_contador = $sheet->getCell("I".$row)->getValue();
                $sql = "insert into contratospendientes (
                    noCliente, 
                    nombreCliente,
            fechaEnvio 
                    fechaActual,
                    contador, 
                    ) value  (
                    '$x_noCliente',
                    '$x_nombreCliente',
                    CAST('$x_fechaEnvio' AS DATE),
                    NOW(),
                    '$x_contador',
                     )";
                $mysqli->query($sql);
            }
        unlink($archivo);
        }   
}
}
echo "<script>
window.location = 'index.php';
</script>
";
?>
```

He hecho un montón de pruebas y he intentado calcular este "contador" en las páginas con php, pero creo que la solución está en calcular este dato en el archivo al importar.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas en PHP, al importar el archivo y ya contar con las variables.

```
$datetime1 = date_create($x_fechaEnvio);
$datetime2 = date_create($x_fechaActual);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a días');
```

Recuerda que el formato de fecha ideal es 'AAAA-MM-DD' es decir, Año 4 dígitos, mes 2 dígitos, y día otros 2 dígitos.

**Mas información**

[date diff](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. SI el resultado tiene que salir en el campo contador? He añadido tu sugerencia al archivo de import.php. " $x_fechaActual = $sheet->getCell("H".$row)->getValue();
                $x_contador = $sheet->getCell("I".$row)->getValue();
                $datetime1 = date_create($x_fechaActual);
                $datetime2 = date_create($x_fechaEnvio);
                $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
                echo $interval->format('%R%a d&#237;as');
                $x_comentarios = $sheet->getCell("J".$row)->getValue();" estaría bien?